# How should I navigate to my sdb drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, winscp

Please find the details of my ubuntu directory,

```
NAME                           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                              8:0    0   300G  0 disk
├─sda1                           8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot 
├─sda2                           8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5                           8:5    0  79.8G  0 part
├─Ubuntu14--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0  75.7G  0 lvm  /
└─Ubuntu14--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                              8:16   0   150G  0 disk
sr0                             11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

when I take remote /home through the WinSCP it seems I am able to have 76GB of memory. Although my sdb which is 150GB is empty. Can anyone help me how to access sdb via WinSCP?

TIA

**Edit 1:**

```
administrator@BLR:~$ df -kh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            126G  4.0K  126G   1% /dev
tmpfs            26G  3.0M   26G   1% /run
/dev/dm-0        75G   58G   14G  82% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            126G   20K  126G   1% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1       236M   77M  147M  35% /boot
```

Comment: You need to mount it but it doesn't look like you have any partitions setup?

Comment: And the partitions would be like `sdb1` or `sdb2` in `sdb` just like `sda1` , `sda2` and `sda5` in `sda`. You will be accessing `sdb1` and  like them.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus , could you please explain a bit more as I am novice in ubuntu.

Comment: Simply said **To access any partition , you must have a mount point**. In your case partition `sda` has mount points with labels as `sad1`, `sda2` and `sda5`, but I don't see any of it for `sdb`.  To make sure a partition has mount points run `df -kh` and look in the last column.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus, i have done that, please see the result. Seems sdb doesn't mounted. Can you please tell me the process how to mount sdb to "/" such that I can get space when I am working through WinSCP.

Comment: "how to mount sdb to `/`" – It looks like what is currently mounted under `/` is an LVM volume. Do you want to add `/dev/sdb` to it? Or move the OS entirely to `/dev/sdb`, so at the end the sole `/dev/sdb` (or better `/dev/sdb1`) would hold your `/`? Or mount `/dev/sdb` (`sdb1`) somewhere else separately?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, Hi, actually the system is a VM and I am accessing the files via WinSCP. Due to the memory constarint of 75 GB, I asked for more space and they allocated me.

sda  increased from 150 to 300 and sdb of 150GB got allocated. But still I am seeing the space for /dev/dm-0 remains 75GB. 

My main agenda to increase the size of the /dev/dm-0

Comment: Please, instead of explaining in comment(s), [edit] the question and add all the relevant information there. Your question should be self-contained and you shouldn't expect users to read all the comments. // *Probably* the procedure will be: (1) create new partitions; (2) add them to LVM; (3) expand `/dev/dm-0`; (4) expand the filesystem within `/dev/dm-0`. // Please paste the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`, `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`, `mount`. This won't show us your LVM setup though. I'm not familiar with LVM, so I can't guide you in this aspect.